# How to return table in JavaScript in Sails.js from multiple models

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I got 2 models, User and Friend. In friend i got 2 columns( UserId1, UserId2)
I want to find in Friend rows where UserId1 is specified, and then from the table with these rows i want to return table with Users with Id = UserId2

```
index: function(req, res, next) {

  Friend.find({UserId1 : req.session.User.id}, function foundUsers(err, friends) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    // pass the array down to the /views/index.ejs page
    res.view({
      friends: friends
    });
  });
}
```

This code above return table with Friends(UserId1, UserId2) where UserId1 is specified, but how to return table with Users (from model User) where Id = UserId2 ??

Answer (score 2):

So, it sounds like you're using the `Friend` model as a join table that represents a friendship between two users.  The query you currently have in your code gets all of the records from the join table where `UserId1` is the id of your logged in user, and for each of those records, you want to get a full `User` object for the user whose id matches the `UserId2` column.  If this is the case, the full code could be something like:

```
index: function(req, res) {

    Friend.find({UserId1 : req.session.User.id})
    .exec(function foundUsers(err, friend_records) {

        if (err) return res.serverError(err);

        // Get an array of all the UserId2 values, using sails.util.pluck,
        // which is essentially Lodash's _.pluck
        var friend_ids = sails.util.pluck(friend_records, 'id');

        // Get the User records for those users.  Using an array
        // in the criteria makes Waterline do an "in" query
        User.find({id: friend_ids}).exec(function(err, friends) {

            // pass the array down to the /views/index.ejs page
            res.view({
                friends: friends
            });

        });

    });

}
```

A couple of notes:

- You should almost never use `next` in your controller code, especially for error handling.  If there's an error, handle it using a response.  Save `next` for [policies](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/policies) unless you really, *really* intend for another controller to handle the response for you.
- Sails v0.10 (currently in beta) includes [support for *associations*](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/ModelAssociations.md), which would handle the join tables for you.